# Unittest for a function throws an exception in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, subprocess, code-coverage, python-unittest

```
class Kill_Tasks:
   def __init__(self):
      self.action = None
      self.cmd=[]
   def kill_tasks(self):
      self.action = False
      #exp task = chrome.exe
      target = 'chrome.exe'
      try:
         self.cmd = suprocess.run(['taskkill','/im', target,'/f'],capture_output=True, check=True)
         self.action = True
      except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
         print(e)
         self.action = False
      return self.cmd
```

Unit Test for a function throws an exception in Python.
The question is: how can I do the Unit Testing for the exception part. I'm doing Code Coverage for this function. But I am not able to check the exception because it's always True. Do I need to do a fake connection to be able to test the exception? Please help me out! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to mock a raised exception.

E.g.

`kill_tasks.py`:

```py
import subprocess


class Kill_Tasks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.action = None
        self.cmd = []

    def kill_tasks(self):
        self.action = False
        # exp task = chrome.exe
        target = 'chrome.exe'
        try:
            self.cmd = subprocess.run(['taskkill', '/im', target, '/f'], capture_output=True, check=True)
            self.action = True
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e)
            self.action = False
        return self.cmd
```

`test_kill_tasks.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from subprocess import CompletedProcess, CalledProcessError
from kill_tasks import Kill_Tasks


class TestKillTasks(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('kill_tasks.subprocess.run')
    def test_kill_tasks_success(self, mock_run):
        mock_run.return_value = CompletedProcess(args=['taskkill', '/im', 'chrome.exe', '/f'], returncode=0)
        kill_tasks_instance = Kill_Tasks()
        cmd = kill_tasks_instance.kill_tasks()
        mock_run.assert_called_once_with(['taskkill', '/im', 'chrome.exe', '/f'], capture_output=True, check=True)
        self.assertIsInstance(cmd, CompletedProcess)
        self.assertTrue(kill_tasks_instance.action)

    @patch('kill_tasks.subprocess.run')
    def test_kill_tasks_exception(self, mock_run):
        mock_run.side_effect = CalledProcessError(returncode=1, cmd='123')
        kill_tasks_instance = Kill_Tasks()
        kill_tasks_instance.kill_tasks()
        self.assertFalse(kill_tasks_instance.action)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66848842/test_kill_tasks.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
Command '123' returned non-zero exit status 1.
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
Name                                            Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66848842/kill_tasks.py           15      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/66848842/test_kill_tasks.py      21      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                              36      0   100%
```

Comment: can you please help me with the next question related to this function?https://stackoverflow.com/q/66896887/15503207